# Prove that if $f \circ T \in E^\star$ for any $ f \in F^\star$, then $T$ is linear and continuous.

Tags: functional-analysis

i'm stucked for a while in this problem:

Let $E, F$ be Banach spaces and suppose $T: E \longrightarrow F$ is an operator such that for
any $f \in \mathrm{F}^{\star},$ we have that $f \circ T \in E^{\star} .$ Prove that $T$ is linear and continuous.

I have some tips to prove this but, i didn't figured why T is linear. It seems to be simple to solve, but i feel that i'm in the wrong path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** if $x,y\in E$ and $\lambda,\mu\in\mathbb R$, then $f(T(\lambda x+\mu y)-\lambda T(x)-\mu T(y))=0$ for all $f\in F^*$.

Comment: Can i use this fact even not knowing that T is linear already? If i could use this, it solves completly the problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can show this identity just using linearity of $f$ and $f\circ T$, and not linearity of $T$.